# Javascript image in div error

Tags: javascript, html

Where is error in this code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="img"></div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var img = document.getElementById("img");
    var x = document.createElement("IMG");
    x.setAttribute("src", "img_pulpit.jpg");
    x.setAttribute("width", "304");
    x.setAttribute("width", "228");
    x.setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock");
    document.img.appendChild(x);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I take id from div, but image isn't load on this div..

I don't know where is error.

thanks in advance

Comment: You're setting the `width` attribute twice. Also make sure the file `img_pullit.jpg` is in the same folder as your html file and remove the `document.` part when calling the `appendChild` function.

Comment: Instead of document.img.appendChild(x); use img.appendChild(x)

Comment: Open the console window in the browser developer tools and you will clearly see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to place your `script` tag before `html`.
use `img.appendChild(x);` instead of `document.img.appendChild(x);`

```html
<script>
   function myFunction() {
      var img = document.getElementById("img");
      var x = document.createElement("IMG");
      x.setAttribute("src", "img_pulpit.jpg");
      x.setAttribute("width", "304");
      x.setAttribute("width", "228");
      x.setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock");
      img.appendChild(x);
   }

</script>
<div id="img"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error lies here `document.img.appendChild(x);`

Change it to `img.appendChild(x);`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="img"></div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var img = document.getElementById("img");
    var x = document.createElement("IMG");
    x.setAttribute("src", "img_pulpit.jpg");
    x.setAttribute("width", "304");
    x.setAttribute("height", "228");    //change width to height
    x.setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock");
    img.appendChild(x);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, you're setting the `width` attribute twice. Change it to `height`